# Change background color for the selected dropdown field

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to change the background color (and font color) only for selected fields on a dropdown menu only with html/css?

Comment: Styling option elements cross browser is notoriously spotty in terms of support.

Answer (score -1):

YES! Only if they are **direct** children of the element.

Example:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<h2>My Title</h2>

CSS:
.header:hover + h2{
   **PUT THE CSS IN HERE**
}
```

Notice that the `h2` is a direct child of the `header`

-- And otherwise, you could use jQuery ;)

Comment: Pardon, but you missed question.

Comment: Well yes of course it's "possible to change the background color (and font color) only for selected fields on a dropdown menu only with html/css"

You can change these things through te use of html and css!

And my answer refers to hovering over it! 
As that makes more sense. 

Or else, again YES, it is possible change the font and color of these things through html and css. 

A fiddle would be nice so I could prove it :)

Comment: If I said you missed question, I thought that example should be related to question. And also not write about jQuery, if in question is written that only with html/css.

Comment: Okay, well the answer to your question is -yes-.
And I didn't say you should use jQuery, I just noted it down for you as an extra option.